# Debian 10 is somehow completely broken apt-get update / upgrade does not work

Tags: debian, certificates

Debian 10 is somehow completely broken apt-get update / upgrade does not work the ca-certificates do not work I try to fix it for too long now but nothing works. that's why I hope someone can help me here. I'm new to Linux Debian and don't know exactly what I did ._. Thank you already :D

apt-get update

````
Err:2 https://packages.sury.org/php buster Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certifica                                                                                                                                                             te issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verificatio                                                                                                                                                             n. [IP: 172.67.182.150 443]
Reading package lists... Done
W: https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/buster/InRelease: No system certificates                                                                                                                                                              available. Try installing ca-certificates.
W: https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/buster/Release: No system certificates av                                                                                                                                                             ailable. Try installing ca-certificates.
E: The repository 'https://packages.sury.org/php buster Release' no longer has a                                                                                                                                                              Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disa                                                                                                                                                             bled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration deta   ```
````

Comment: You might have a problem with the CA-certficates. Does `update-ca-certificates --fresh` then running `apt` again help? Also take a closer look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/891734/debian-wheezy-outdated-root-certificates).

Comment: hey thanks unfortunately, ```update-ca-certificates --fresh```does not work for me it comes 
```- bash: update-ca-certificates: command not found```

i also tried with```apt-get install-y ca-certificates``` to install but there comes

```Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package ca-certificates is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ca-certificates' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with Debian.  It's with `https://packages.sury.org/php`.  That's a 3rd party repository.

First, ensure that your `buster` installation (without the PHP stuff) is good and will handle certificates:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list{,.bak}
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl
```

Next, if (and only if) you trust the source, then restore `php.list` and get the latest signature:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/source.list.d/php.list{.bak,}
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
sudo apt update
```

---

Edit:  It sounds like you've lost your main Debian archive source.  re-create it with:

```
echo "deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ buster main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then try again

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
`sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package ca-certificates is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ca-certificates' has no installation candidate`
I'm sorry if I miss something obvious :/

Comment: Was your `apt update` successful?

Comment: [The release file](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz) describes `ca-certificates 20200601~deb10u2` and `ca-certificates_20200601~deb10u2_all.deb` exists in the [pool](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/ca-certificates/).  Is it possible you've deleted the main debian archive from your sources?  What's the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`?

Comment: apt update was successful I think:
```apt update
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.``` 
and the cat output was:
```cat: /etc/apt/sources.list: **No such file or directory**``` is this the reason?
```deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ buster main```

Comment: Probably, Usually lines relevant to the main debian archive are kept in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. If you don't have `/etc/apt/sources.list` it could be in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` but also possibly missing. Ensure `/etc/apt/sources.list` exists and contains `deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ buster main`.  You might choose to use a different mirror, or append `non-free contrib`, but that's  up to you.  Then `apt update` again and repeat the solution above.

Comment: oh, that sounds complicated .-. can't I create this sources.list myself somehow?

Comment: Instructions added to the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!!